# How can I add the " difference in percentage" on top of bar in R shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps

I have plotted a bar in R shiny as follow:

[image]

Now, I need to show the respective value of y axis and also the difference in percentage between 2nd and 1st bar( decrease rate from right to left in percentage).

My server.R is :

```
output$plot1 <- renderPlot({

plot <- ggplot(data = phnData1_load(df), aes_string(x="quarter", y = input$column1))
plot <- plot + geom_col(fill = blue)
plot <- plot + xlab("QUARTER")
plot

})
```

UI

```
selectInput(inputId = "column1", label = "Select a column to plot against Quarter", choices = c("ACN","BCN"))
```

Y axis is taking the value of input of column1 as dynamic/reactive way.
I am not having so much clue  how to go ahead to get the desired measure of decrease from Right to left. Looking for your kind help.

Thanks

Comment: This has got nothing to do with Shiny as far as I can see  - it's just a ggplot question and quite a straightforward one. Have a look at [this](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2021/09/adding-text-labels-to-ggplot2-bar-chart/).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is close to what you are seeking?

```
df <- data.frame(quarter = c('q1', 'q2'), 
                 value = c(43000, 47000))
  
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = quarter, y = value)) + 
  geom_col(fill = 'blue') +
  geom_text(aes(label = value),
            vjust = -0.5) +
  annotate('text', 
           x =1.5, 
           y = max(df$value) + 1500, 
           label = paste0('Difference = ',  min(df$value) - max(df$value)), 
           fontface = 2)
```

You will need to provide more of your code from the Shiny UI for a full solution, but you should be able to generalize from here
[image: sample]

Comment: thanks.I have edited UI part in main post.Y axis is taking the value of input of column1 as dynamic/reactive way.

Comment: You will need to add your dataframe too

Comment: Data frame has 3 attributes: Quarter, ACN,BCN where the aggregation/sum of  ACN and BCN are feeding as input$column1 against Quarter.Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not quite enough detail. Please update your post with the output from dput(df). Run (dput(df), the copy the contents from the console. Then paste into your original post